# Replacing main electircal to house and fixing an old mess

Tags: electrical, power-supply

I am changing the main electrical lead to going from roof to buried. The pole with the meter has a main panel with 3 breakers (100a to house, 40a to pump house, 40a to barn). I wish to upgrade the house to 150a or 200a. The main panel for the house is 100 feet away from the house main panel. I am using 3awg copper wire. My main issue is getting a 150a or 200a breaker that works in this standard box and this size wire? or is there a replace box that has a main 200a for the house and supports secondary breakers for the other locations.. or should I install a new box off the meter for the house that can also feed the other locations...

Comment: 3AWG copper tops out at 100 amps, so perhaps you need to actually plan this out a bit further and better (and with aluminum wires unless you love wasting money) if you want to upgrade to 150 or 200A to the house. [Edit]ing to provide your location (at the state/county/province level is usually enough precision) and utility will help some folks to provide more on-point answers for your specific location.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, who is your electric utility, and why are you using copper wire?

Comment: To upgrade from 100 to 150/200 will need to see if local power company will do it, the transformer on the pole needs to change.  Panels usually rated/sold by amps, so will need a new panel for 150 or 200 amps(usually comes with main breaker).

Comment: Get us a photo of the main panel, preferably with the cover off. It may already have provision for delivering the full 200A off the main breaker.   There is no such thing as a standard breaker or box. Any line's breakers *properly* fit only their panels, with the exception of UL-Classified breakers made *specifically for* a competitor's panel.

Comment: Thanks for all the input... I have several pictures that would help explain the current installation but not sure how best to post it?

Comment: I am located in California and use PG&E...

Comment: Just to clarify the replace wire is THHN 3/0 Str Cu SIM BK 500R - 600v